# Using bootstrap besides jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I want to start my GUI for a little web application. I was thinking about using bootstrap, at the same time I also was thinking about JQuery. Actually I thought this makes sense. But I started to wonder, after reading a post here, which mentioned, that jQuery was not used anymore, because some plugin in bootstrap was found.

The actual question is basically: Does it make sense to use jQuery besides bootstrap? Or would it make more sense to just use html(5) with jQuery?

Thanks in advance
Meru

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: bootstrap.js requires jQuery.

Comment: Whoever said jQuery isn't used any more is wrong, it's still the most popular javascript library going - http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript You shouldn't base your decision to use it on whether other people use it. Also, this isn't a question, you're just looking for discussion, stack overflow isn't the place for this.

Comment: @Snixtor: Oh, basically I really asked this to myself... Well because, having a glance to both, they both for example manipulate css-classes and don't they interfere then? And for what would I use what then...? But anyhow, thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it makes sense! First of all jQuery is used for all the Bootstrap Javascript plugins. Bootstrap provides a sceleton for your pages that supports four screen resolutions. Furthermore, Bootstrap provides a set of nice components. Personally I always use both Bootstrap and jQuery at all my projects.

**UPDATE**

As an option, you can use [Bootstrap for AngularJs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). In this case you definitely shouldn't use jQuery :-)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript components of Bootstrap *require* JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is used for all the Bootstrap Javascript plugins. [It says it on the Bootstrap site.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

here:

> Bring Bootstrap's components to life with over a dozen custom jQuery plugins. Easily include them all, or one by one.

and here:

> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you include plugins individually, make sure to check for these dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files). Consult our bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

Comment: Ok, well, so if the plugins are enough for me, I'd just use those and if I want to do own stuff, I just use jquery with it. Correct? Thanks for that answer.